# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz$$

According to info provided by @skbmoore:

Gradshteyn, Izrail Solomonovich, and Iosif Moiseevich Ryzhik. Table of integrals, series, and products. Academic press, 2014. Eq.3.914.1 and 3.914.4

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+exp(-sqrt(a%5E2%2Bx%5E2))) says no.

Comment: @mrtaurho, thanks for your reply. I tried WolframAlpha before. But the image shown above reveal the relation to  modified Bessel functions of second kind. I am confused about how to derive the relation.

Comment: Make sure to include such details the next time right away. Hence questions of the type "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received here on MSE :)

Comment: The integral in the OP is an indefinite integral while the integration in the cited paper is a definite integral.

Comment: @Mark Viola, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $R =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, I think the integration range is -inf to +inf.

Comment: Put $z = a\sinh(t)$.

Comment: @Count Iblis, if $$z=asinh(t)$$, it does relate to K0 and K1. But it is not physically related to statement in the paper I mentioned. Maybe that paper use some approximations which is not clearly stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradshteyn and Ryzhik have several integrals of this type.  For instance, eq. 3.914.1 has

$$ \int_0^\infty \exp{(-\beta\,\sqrt{a^2+z^2}\,)} \cos{(b\,z)} \, dz = \frac{\beta \, a}{\sqrt{\beta^2+b^2}} K_1\big(a \sqrt{\beta^2+b^2} \, \big.)$$

Set $\beta=1$ and $b=0$ to get the answer you need.  References to this formula are given, so if you want to know how it was derived, you might examine those.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!@skbmoore

Comment: is it possible to integrate if I started integrate from t (a value) to inf ?

Answer (score 1):

By assuming $a>0$ and letting $x=a\sinh z$ we have
$$ I(a)=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\,dx = 2a \int_{0}^{+\infty}\cosh(z) e^{-a\cosh z}\,dz \tag{1}$$
and
$$ I(a)=2a\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{u e^{-au}}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du =2a e^{-a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{v+1}{\sqrt{v^2+2v}} e^{-av}\,dv\tag{2}$$
such that $I(a)$ is clearly related to the Laplace transform of $\frac{v+1}{\sqrt{v^2+2v}}$ and it is given by $2a e^{-a}$ times a log-convex function. Equivalently
$$ I(a) = 2e^{-a}+2ae^{-a}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-av}}{\sqrt{v^2+2v}(v+1+\sqrt{v^2+2v})}\,dv\tag{3}$$
which in combination with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality allows tight approximations for $a\approx 0$ or $a\gg 0$.
By the very definition of $K_1$ we have $I(a)= 2a\,K_1(a)$ and tight lower bounds can be derived from $\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\geq 1+\frac{1}{2u^2}$ and Cauchy-Schwarz, again. Unsurprisingly, $I(a)$ behaves like the density of a normal distribution close to the origin and like the density of a Laplace distribution far from the origin.