# How to integrate $\int_{t_2}^{t_1} \exp(-\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> $$\int_{t_2}^{t_1} \exp(-\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz$$

where $a>0$

One related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953892/570843) in which the integration range is $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

In Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's book **3.461**, I found the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp(-\beta\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz=aK_1(a\beta)$$

Let's simplify it to solve

> $$\int_{0}^{t} \exp(-\sqrt{a^2+z^2}) dz$$

Comment: I think you can't.

Comment: I  expected it to be very difficult.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, do you anything to say about why it can't be solved?

Comment: What is $K_1$  ?

Comment: K1 is modified Bessel functions of the second kind of order one...

Answer (score 0):

Do you get to something interesting if you try thr variable change z=acos(x)? Then maybe some complex analysis

Comment: if so, z can only be in the range of [-a, a], which is not useful for me.

Comment: The natural substitution is $z = a \tan(x),$ to exploit $1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x.$ It is unclear if this would help with the incomplete integral, though.

Comment: It seems that it only removes the sqrt root, not making the integral simple.